# Js_of_ocaml store types in js

Tags: javascript, ocaml

I'm playing around with a React wrapper in js_of_ocaml.
In my OCaml interface to React every component is a module which contains a type props and type state. Those types will be passed to the actual react props & state, so they need to be convert to js with Js.Unsafe.inject at some point. Example with props (just a string here):

```
type props = string
type jsval = Js.js_string Js.t
let from_js jsv = Js.to_string jsv
let to_js ov = Js.string ov
```

To actually use those props, I'll need to get the props type corresponding value back out of the js React props, hence the from_js. 
So props & state, a custom type in every component module, needs to be stored in javascript props & state and they need to be converted back.
This introduces a lot of boilerplate, look at the example above with props as a simple string. For every component module I'll need to define this for both props & state. Imagine type props being a complex record... How do I easily convert that to js and get it back out?

Is there a way somehow to just store a custom type in javascript and get it back in an ocaml type without having to convert it with those functions?

Comment: You can try this ppx rewriter to automatically generate to/from conversions: http://github.com/little-arhat/ppx_jsobject_conv. Also, you may be interested in some code I wrote regarding react integration — https://github.com/little-arhat/ocaml-fb-react-playground

Comment: Thanks for the response! I basically started with your repo and the gist jordwalke posted :) 
Did you ever consider implementing lifecycle methods?
I mean what if a module needs to implement componentWillReceiveProps  and another shouldn't ? Did you have any types in mind to feed to the defcomponent functor?